# Repeated in the table

Tags: php, html, while-loop, html-table, smarty

I have a problem in in the table

The problem is to repeat
I want when it reaches 4 rows to the table is transferred to the new line

Code PHP :

```
// for : 
$tr = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($post_tv)){ 
    $show[] = $row; 
    if ($tr == 4){
        $tr == 1;
    }
    $tr++;   
    $marsosmarty->assign("show",$show); 
    $marsosmarty->assign("tr",$tr);
}
```

Code Html smarty :

```
<td width="91"><table width="100" height="100" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#666666">
    <tbody><tr>
        {section name=table loop=$show}  
        {if $tr eq 3} </tr><tr> {/if} 
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <a href="./channel.php?id={$show[table].id}" target="az">
                <img src="{$show[table].a_IMG}" alt="{$show[table].a_DESC}" width="100" height="100" border="0" class="link-img" title="{$show[table].a_TITLE}">
            </a>
        </td>
        {/section} 
    </tr>
```

Comment: What is the problem, what doesn't work?

Comment: I dont understand your question. Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

use the below code. In your code you are comparing the tr with the value, you have to assign

```
if ($tr == 4){
        $tr = 1;
    }
```